# xml tag with attribute name changing using lua

Tags: lua

I am new in `lua` and i would like to change `XML` tag and `attribute` name. My XML is:

```
<art>
    <fm>
    <art-meta>
            <his>
            <date date-type="rec"><day>23</day><month>1</month><year>2002</year></date>
            <date date-type="acc"><day>21</day><month>4</month><year>2002</year></date>
            </his>
    </art-meta>
    </fm>
</art>
```

I had tried `FileGlobal = string.gsub(FileGlobal,"<date data-type=\"rec\">", "<date-rec>")` and doesn't work?

I would like to change `<date date-type="rec">` to `<date-rec>`. How to achieve this?

Comment: Few issues: You have a typo in either your pattern (gsub's second parameter) or your XML. The xml says date *date*-type and the gsub pattern says date *data*-type. You need to escape the dash '-' (a special character in Lua patterns by prefixing a % sign: date%-type. Also, instead of escaping the quotation marks you could just use single quotes to enclose the string. Working pattern: `'<date date%-type="rec">'`

Comment: @Allister please don't answer questions with comments.

Comment: @Allister: It's working fine and please post your answer i will accept for future reference.

Comment: @Piglet OK I just posted my response as an answer with a little bit of information that would elucidate the problem for someone coming here from google. I didn't think I did anything wrong with my comment, considering I see people answer in the comments all the time, and my "answer" was 99% just me pointing out the OP's typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the pattern (the second parameter of gsub) which looks for `date data-type` instead of what we see in the xml, `date date-type`.
Beyond that, there is an actual issue in the pattern to be aware of:
Lua patterns use special characters, like `- $ ^ () [ %`. You must escape the `-` in `date-type` like this: `date%-type`.
To a lesser extent, it is also worth noting that you don't need to escape the double quotation marks (although this would work). You can wrap your strings in single quotes or double brackets and the double quotes inside will be recognized as part of the string.
Example: `'Foo "egg" bar'` or `[[Foo "egg" bar]]`
Final example of a working pattern: Typo fixed, dash escaped.
`'<date date%-type="rec">'`